# MVC 4 refreshing partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view inside of my main parent view that contains a table I need to update. The reason it's in a partial view is so that I can update it without reloading my main view. I can't use a form here because I'm inside of one in my parent view.

**Partial View:**

```
@model IList<ItemViewModel>

@Html.ActionLink("Add Item", "AddItem", "Home", new { model = Model }, null)

<table>
    ...
    @{foreach (var item in Model)
        //add table row
    }
    ....
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult AddItem(IList<ItemViewModel> model)
{
    model.Add(...);
    return View("_PartialView", model);
    //also tried return PartialView(...)
}
```

Everything works for the most part but when my ActionResult returns, my parent view is gone and all I see is the partial. I guess that makes sense when I'm returning a partial view, but how do I just refresh it inside of the parent?

Comment: You will need some client side code.  Under what conditions do you need to refresh?

Comment: show the code for parent view

Comment: Refreshing only part of a page with data from the server requires javascript to accomplish. You will need to use an ajax request.

Comment: @Maess When an item is added, I need to add it to the model and display new row(s).

Comment: @Travis J How do I bind the result back to the model after ajax request?

Comment: @aw04 C Sharper provides a good first step in his answer for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Main view Here is your Partial.

```
<div id="partialSummaryDiv">@{Html.RenderAction("GetSummary", "Order");}</div>
```

On some event you'll have your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Order/GetContractTotals",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
         // refreshes partial view
        $('#partialSummaryDiv').html(result);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetContractTotals()
    {
       // blah blah
        return PartialView("_OrderContractTotals", octvm);        
    }
```

Comment: $('#partialContractTotalsDiv') ->  $('#partialSummaryDiv') ?

Comment: This is a good place for you to start @aw04. Note that, this would be in some client side event (as in `$("#myElement").click(function(){/*call ajax in here*/});`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/DeleteCustomerDetail",
            data: { "id": id },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#CustomerPartial").load("/Admin/_partialCustomers/", { id: DealerId });
            }
        });
```

In Controller

```
public void DeleteCustomerDetail(int Id)
{
           //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main view, put your partial into a div:

```
  <div id='additemDiv'>
        // partial goes here
    </div>
```

In your partial give the anchor an id:

```
@model IList<ItemViewModel>

<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='addItemLink'>Add Item </a>

<table>
    ...
    @{foreach (var item in Model)
        //add table row
    }
    ....
</table>
```

You will need the click event of the link bound:

```
$(#'addItemLink').on('click', function(){
     $.get('your url', function(data){
        $('#additemDiv').html(data);
     })
});
```

And your action:

```
public ActionResult AddItem(IList<ItemViewModel> model)
{
    model.Add(...);
    return PartialView(model);
}
```