# Ajax request using querystring

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

"        I have a controller which have Dropdown list and On change of DDL bindind a calling Index view again and returning partial view which loads content as :
    **Index Controller :**

```
public ActionResult Index(ProductEntity Prod, string CategoryId)
{
ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(ObjStore.categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
var model = ObjStore.products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == Prod.CategoryId);
return PartialView("_ProductMaster", model);
}
else if (CategoryId != "" && CategoryId !=null)
{
var model = ObjStore.products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == Prod.CategoryId);
return PartialView("_ProductMaster", model);
}
return View();
}
```

Partial VIEW :

```
    @model IEnumerable<StoreManagement.Models.ProductEntity>

    <div id="Products">

    @if (Model != null)
    {    

    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name </th>
            <th>Max Qty</th>
            <th>Min Qty</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr> 

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ProductName.ToString()</td>
                <td>@item.MaxQty</td>
                <td>@item.MinQty</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditProduct",new {ProductId=@item.ProductId},null)</td>
            </tr>        
        } 

    </table>
    }
    </div>
```

In above I have Edit Action Link which is redirecting to Edit View and On this Page I have Back action link which is redirecting to Index controller with query string as CategoryId which I am using in selecting Dropdownlist.

Now I want to Load Index view with the CategoryId as querystring.

'Else code is working for this'

```
              if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    var model = ObjStore.products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == Prod.CategoryId);
                    return PartialView("_ProductMaster", model);
                }
                else if (CategoryId != "" && CategoryId !=null)
                {
                    var model = ObjStore.products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == Prod.CategoryId);
                    return PartialView("_ProductMaster", model);
                }
```

but it returns only partial view. I want that view load with their _layout page. or is there any way to call onchange event of DDL if we have query string in URl?or make Request.IsAjaxRequest()true."

Comment: Check this out, it looks like this guy had a similar problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608567/mvc-4-refreshing-partial-view/21608718#21608718

Comment: Not find any solution....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the layout page aswel, you should return as a View and not as a PartialView

```
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var model = ObjStore.products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == Prod.CategoryId);
                return View("_ProductMaster", model);
            }
            else if (CategoryId != "" && CategoryId !=null)
            {
                var model = ObjStore.products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == Prod.CategoryId);
                return View("_ProductMaster", model);
            }
```